# How to get mvc c# user role in jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a function in jQuery to disable input based on user roles. But I don't know how to get the current ASP.Net MVC user role in jQuery.

Below is the code but it is not working:

```
$(function () {
        if (Roles.IsUserInRole('user'))
        {
            $("#GenericName").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#TradeName").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#Form").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#Strength").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#IsBrandSubstitutionAllowed").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#Route").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#Dosages").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#Unit").prop("disabled", true);     
            $("#PackTypes").prop("disabled", true);  
            $("#GeneratedDirection").prop("disabled", true);  
            $("#UserDirection").prop("disabled", true);  
            $("#StartDate").prop("disabled", true);  
            $("#EndDate").prop("disabled", true); 
        }
    });
```

Comment: what error u are facing ?

Comment: no error. it is just not working.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**The problem:** You are mixing Javascript and Razor Views.

What you have:

```
if (Roles.IsUserInRole('user')) 
{
```

should actually **be written as**:

```
var userRole = '@(Roles.IsUserInRole("user") ? "true" : "false")';
if(userRole) {
   ...
```

This code `@(Roles.IsUserInRole('user') ? "true" : "false")` will output `true` or `false` literal string (as it's not wrapped in single or double quotes, javascript will interpreter as a boolean value) and you can just use that new assign variable.

---

What I normally do, is in my `_Layout.cshtml` view, I add a simple Global Javascript that I can easily call through my application... for example and assuming that you have a `CurrentUser` object on that View (through ViewData or Model):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Your App</title>
    <styles ... >

    <script>
       var AppGlobal = {
           "user" = {
               "name" : "@(CurrentUser.Name)",
               "id"   : "@(CurrentUser.Guid.ToString())",
               "role" : "@(CurrentUser.Role.Name)"
           },
           ...
       };
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
     @RenderBody()
  </body>
</html>
```

Then it's easier, in your case to do:

```
if(AppGlobal.user.role === 'user') {
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is the answer that i'm looking for. To combine the jQuery and Razor views. And thank you for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to do an AJAX call in order to get user role.

After ajax calling, based on response received then you disable/enable inputs.

like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'Controller1/Action1',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {},
  type: 'post',
  success: function(data){
    if(data.user === 'user') {
       // disable inputs here !
    }
  }
});
```

and your controller called `Controller1Controller`:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Action1(){
   return Json(new {
      user =  // put current user role here !
   });
}
```

Also, I'd suggest to use `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` in order to avoid CSRF attack but seems to be fine since there are no form.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is an eye opening to get data from Controller using Json. I have never done that before.

Answer (score 1):

```
var userRole = '@(User.IsInRole("user") ? "true" : "false")';
if(userRole) {
   ...
```

In my case I had to use the if condition like this

```
If(userRole=="true"){
    ...
}
```

then the code hit the condition else it was skipping it.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use C# code, like Roles.IsUserInRole('user') if you're writing JavaScript code in Razor view.

As a workaround, you can create an action to tell you the user's permission or maybe role, which you will need to send a request to, every time permissions are needed. You can also keep a copy of the status returned to save subsequent requests. According to your project, you can use it with more sophistication and make separate your authorization logic.

Answer (score 0):

Using MVC 5.2.2, this worked for me

```
var userRoleAdmin = '@(Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("Admin")) ? "true" : "false")';
if(userRoleAdmin) {
   ...
```